# TwilioConversation hang up the invite from calling end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, twilio, twilio-api

Is there any method to reject the just sent invite on twilioconversation. Once, i invite and if the error occurs because of timeout, the error is emitted to only calling end and not on the being called end.

```
 $scope.callUser = function(beingCalledId) {

        if (activeConversation) {
            // add a participant
            activeConversation.invite(beingCalledID);

        } else {
            //create a conversation
            var options = {};
            if (previewMedia) {
                options.localMedia = previewMedia;
            }
            conversationsClient.inviteToConversation(beingCalledId, options).then(
                conversationStarted,
                function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            );
        }
    };
```

Even the beingCalled end doesnot recieve the call, `Error_conversation_invitation` is emitted. However, the call is still ringing on the `beingCalled(recieving end)`. Is there a method like:

```
conversationsClient.rejectJustSentInvitation();
```

**How do we hang up the call from the calling end in twilio?? Recieving end can reject the call which is fine? what about the calling end?**

**EDIT:** Are there no events emitted such as failed? or canceled?

```
conversationsClient.on('failed', function(invite) {
            $scope.modal2.hide();
            $scope.modal1.hide();
            invite.reject();
        });

conversationsClient.on('canceled', function(invite) {
                $scope.modal2.hide();
                $scope.modal1.hide();
                invite.reject();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you call `inviteToConversation` it returns an [`OutgoingInvite`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/0.13.5/docs/OutgoingInvite.html) which is a promise that eventually resolves to a `Conversation`.

However, the API currently implements promises as cancelable. So, you can call [`cancel()`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/0.13.5/docs/OutgoingInvite.html#cancel) on the promise any time up until it is either rejected or fulfilled.

Let me know if this helps at all!

**[edit]**

For greater clarity, here's an example. Instead of just chaining on the promise that you receive from the call to `inviteToConversation` you can save it as a variable. Then later, if you need to cancel it, call `cancel` on it:

```
var invitePromise = conversationsClient.inviteToConversation(beingCalledId, options)
invitePromise.then(conversationStarted, function(error) {
  alert(error);
});

// Then sometime later, if you need to cancel the invite

invitePromise.cancel();
```

Hope that helps.

**[edit again]**

On the beingCalled end you can listen for canceled and failed events on the [`IncomingInvite`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/0.13.5/docs/IncomingInvite.html#event:canceled) object.

```
conversationsClient.on('invite', function(invite) {
  // show modal for accepting the call

  invite.on('canceled', function(event) {
    // hide modal
  });

  invite.on('failed', function(event) {
    // hide modal
  })
})
```

Comment: philnash, i had already seen the doc, but couldn't quite get it codewise. Can you give a code example of cancel. would be more than grateful. Sorry, but i am noob here.

Comment: can you see my edit as well. If that can give more clarification. canceling promise does nothing at all. Infact upon logging invitePromise, i got a blank object "{}". Does the timeout error on calling end not reject the invitation sent on twilio. Cause its emitting nothing on the beingCalled end.

Comment: Ah, I might have messed something up with the promises. Check the latest code which sets `invitePromise` to the original `OutgoingInvite` rather than the result of calling `then` on it.

Comment: As for the beingCalled end, I thought you had an error and wanted to cancel an invite. What are you doing to the invite on the other side? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Oh, hold on, the incomingInvite can receive canceled events. I'll edit the answer again.

Comment: Hi philnash, i had already figured it out by the time. Thank you so much for your help. I do have another question regarding twilio. Hope you can help in that as well. I will be creating a new thread for that.

Comment: here is the link to the second thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394026/twilio-improper-behavior-after-first-call